# Custom Body of Webform email handler missing text area

Tags: 8, webforms

When selecting default, I have the html appearing.  Selecting twig will work as well.  Selecting Custom Body changes to a blank area with no way to enter code.  This happens on both lamp and live site. see image

[image: missing body text]

Comment: What is being logged in your browser's JS console. Also see https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?text=missing+editor&status=All&version=8.x

Comment: yes, ckeditor plugin.js file somehow not available, will attempt to reinstall ckeditor with composer

Answer (score 0):

At jrockowitz suggestion I found the issue, in case someone else has same issue,
ckeditor could not find the plugin.js file and related files.  I moved them as below and it works.
was: ckeditor.link/ with a folder called link and plugin.js
now: ckeditor.link/ with folders dialogs, icons, images, lang and plugin.js file